# Multi-color headrule in a latex document

Tags: header-footer

I wish to have a head rule that is composed of 3 or more different colors as shown in the picture below:
[image: My desired output]
So far, I have managed to create a single-colored head rule as shown in the picture below though I want a multicolored one.
[image: My problem description]
Below is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,openany,twoside]{book}  
\raggedbottom
\let\cleardoublepage=\clearpage
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\HRule{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1.5pt}}
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hhline}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\renewcommand\headrule
{{      \color{red}%
        \hrule height 2.5pt
        width\headwidth
        }}  
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[noindentafter,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage[courier]{quotchap}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand\sectfont{\bfseries}
\usepackage{calc} 
\newcommand*\myheaderfooterfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[ragged]{sidecap}
\usepackage[marginal]{footmisc}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vspace*{-3pt}%
    \hrule width 2in height 1.4pt \vspace*{2.6pt}}
\setlength\footnotemargin{10pt}  

\begin{document} 
    \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With three color equal long rule segments:

```
\documentclass[11pt,openany,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm, vmargin=3cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\headrule
{{     \color{blue}\rule{0.33\headwidth}{2.5pt}%   <---
       \color{red}\rule{0.34\headwidth}{2.5pt}%    <---
       \color{orange}\rule{0.33\headwidth}{2.5pt}% <---
}}
\usepackage{helvet}
\newcommand*\myheaderfooterfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Zarko. The solution worked perfectly!

Comment: How do I remove the headers at the beginning every chapter @Zarko?

Comment: @itc, that is new question ;-). As it as such... Your comment is not clear. Your code already not produce page headers on the page at beginning of `\chapter`. Headers start on the second page of chapter.